# Calculating uncertainty of a measurement

Tags: measurements

When measuring some quantity we express it with a value followed by an uncertainty:

For example: The answers of a previous task I completed. $$0.250±0.001$$
$$0.75±0.1$$
$$1.20±0.02$$
$$68.73±0.03$$
$$0.770±0.006$$
$$153±1$$

I'm trying to understand how the value and uncertainty are rounded. From my observation, I've noticed that the uncertainty is always rounded to 1sf. Furthermore, I've also noticed that the value is always rounded to the same decimal place as the uncertainty. Are these two observations true in general?

I'm also trying to understand why my second observation is the case. I think if the value contained more decimal places than the uncertainty, it wouldn't really mean anything. In a sense the uncertainty would kind of render the additional decimal places useless. Could this be correct? Is there a nicer intuition for why this is the case or a refined explanation?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in all accounts and this is usually taught in lab intros. The intuition you've presented is spot on. A lot of the time you'll also see uncertainties with two sigfigs if the uncertainty's most significant figure is 1 or 2, as this leaves less wiggle room for the uncertain digits at the end of the value (e.g. $1.56\pm0.13$ instead of $1.6\pm0.1$).

Comment: I am not sure as to your reason for quoting the error to two significant figures.  Even though there is limited information, if a statistical test is performed to see if the two values are different it is found that there is no significant difference between them.

Comment: @Farcher The reasoning for this given to me in lab class way back when is that for 1 or 2 the next-to-leading digit substantially affects the size of the uncertainty. The range $1.0 - 1.5$ could quite literally be the difference between $2\sigma$ and $3\sigma$.

Comment: It's the same deal when you buy cheap resistors and half of the decade is reserved for 1s and 2s. Proportionally the second digit makes way more difference in those ranges.

Comment: I understand the difference between the two significant figures of $0.98$ and the three significant figures of $1.02$.  Assuming that the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution is given the percentage of values between $1.55$ and $1.57$ is as follows: for $1.6 \pm 0.1$ it is $8.4\%$; for $1.56\pm 0.13$ it is $6.1\%$; and for $1.56 \pm 0.1$ it is $8.0\%$.  Not really that much of a difference?